# How to narrow discriminated union based on Record key value

Tags: typescript

I have a union type whose elements have a discriminator property called "type". I then declare a Record<> whose keys are the "type" property values.

How do I declare the Record's second generic parameter (Record< , ***this param***>) such that values in the map/record are inferred based on the corresponding key?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDmyDeAoZZMATwAcIAuZAcgBMtqBuA5AIygglqoGcwpQmZgF88oSLEQoAahAAWwBABsU+QiXJVqAN3mKVTFgFs4ADwD6PclyogArkdbQRzPBpQAVBSGwBeNFjIAD7IsgrKEK4I6CB8yKQC4ACycKRUAEoQ0VC0ADxeggDa1O7UALoANMgAFGDemFQFPgCUyL4AfMh8iZid-mo09JjUVKZtnQAGGNgAJDimAHTsnLTCExUshFvbO9sA9HvIAHonJyw6ehEjyGMdyBNh+igmY1bktMhziy+W1qsTm12QOBIJ2B2Op0hRzwwiAA)

```typescript
interface Dog {
  type: 'dog';
  breed: string;
}

interface Vehicle {
  type: 'vehicle';
  max_speed: number;
};

type Thing = Dog | Vehicle;

const printMap: Record<Thing['type'], (thing: Thing) => string> = {
  'dog': x => `Dog ${x.breed}`,
                    // ^^^^^ Property 'breed' does not exist on type 'Thing'. Property 'breed' does not exist on type 'Vehicle'.
                    // How do I make TypeScript infer `x` is a Dog because the key/property name is 'dog'?
  'vehicle': x => `Vehicle max spped ${x.max_speed}`
                                      // ^^^^^^^^^ Property 'max_speed' does not exist on type 'Thing'. Property 'max_speed' does not exist on type 'Dog'.
                                      // How do I make TypeScript infer `x` is a Vehicle because the key/property name is 'vehicle'?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a [`Record<K, V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) for this, since you need different types for each property value, but `Record<K, V>` has the same property type `V` for each key.  Instead you need to build a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that [`Extract`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) the relevant member of the discriminated union for each property.  Possibly like this:

```
type DiscriminatedUnionHandler<T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>, K extends keyof T, R> =
  { [P in T[K]]: (foo: Extract<T, Record<K, P>>) => R }
```

Here the `DiscriminatedUnionHandler<T, K, R>` takes a discriminated union type `T`, its discriminant key name `K`, and the return type `R` of the individual handler functions.   The resulting type has properties for each value of `T[K]` (which is `"dog" | "vehicle"` for `Thing`) and the corresponding property is a function that accepts the relevant member of `T` and returns `R`.

For `Thing` this looks like:

```
type DiscriminatedUnionHandler<T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>, K extends keyof T, R> =
  { [P in T[K]]: (foo: Extract<T, Record<K, P>>) => R }

interface Dog {
  type: 'dog';
  breed: string;
}
interface Vehicle {
  type: 'vehicle';
  max_speed: number;
};

type Thing = Dog | Vehicle;

const printMap: DiscriminatedUnionHandler<Thing, "type", string> = {
  'dog': x => `Dog ${x.breed}`,
  'vehicle': x => `Vehicle max spped ${x.max_speed}`
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgSwM4GMBOCC2CB2BDEKAEwFUcEB7HACTxyIBso0AeAFRigA9D6kYASlBQU0RFgGkANDAAKaCtDTgJUMAD4ZEzjyh8YAazUUAZjDYyB6mAF5gMGAG8YAbVkxc5lxIC6PgFwwABQmFBSBAKI8aHgoIOyWwqLi0nLq6gCUttYCMAC+wIW4hGgmsbBwFADmTvYw4NCBAORE1U0A3HUARmhQxIFIIBg4VZ0FxcxlKLAAalAAFggoTLUODVDNAG4LS0wddZh4XAD6SND9MDgArphdzGOdoJCwbIsjtvDVMAA+MHOLyygjxEOEGMAgwxAAFk8BBAohUBhsPhCKRyFRaPQmKxXrgqjIAETrAkyQbDKrWGyrGAtNqBLjZGAAA0qNQAJI4uAA6Hp9Ih5JlSOpNbYAvb0xlM-67WCHBlnaBEGAc7ly07nflMwp5IA)

Comment: whoops, thanks for the edit. Not sure how I copied your code in instead of mine